# Change responses status code from WCF Service which is returning System.IO.Stream?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service in WCF which implements the following interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataStream
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet( UriTemplate = "/?format=tab")]
    System.IO.Stream GetDataAsStream();
}
```

Now my class which implements this creates a stream, then launches a thread which will write to the stream. The method then immediately returns the stream.

The issue is, once the thread is started, how can it change the StatusCode of the response? I've tried passing the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` to the thread so it can change the `StatusCode` , but it seems like even if I do that, as soon as I close the stream, the client gets a status code of 200.